# Does cybersource accept multiple card information

Tags: payment-gateway

I am working on a project where the customer pays for the product using third party tool provided by Cybersource. We have a scenario where the user has to pay a part of the amount as downpayment and for the remaining amount he may choose the recurring payment option.

The problem araises when the user uses 2 different cards for making the payment. The first card for paying the downpayment amount and the second card for making the installment payments.

Is there a way we can send information of both the cards to cybersource ? We have already managed to pass the information of one card for paying the downpayment  amount, but cannot figure out the field names which needs to be used for passing the other card information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do two payments at one time. What you need to do is send one partial payment over and then do a separate transaction for the remaining balance. You need to keep a few things in mind like:

- You don't want to process the second payment if the first payment is declined
- If the second payment is declined you need to remember to void the frist payment. If not you risk getting a chargeback.